# Add values in second array depending upon the values in first array

Tags: php, arrays

Here's the situation:

Suppose I have first Array as:

```
Array(
    [0] => Person1
    [1] => Person1
    [2] => Person2
)
```

And second array as:

```
Array(
    [0] => 100.00
    [1] => 150.25
    [2] => 157.15
)
```

How do I add values (`100.00` + `150.25`) of second Array and merge them (`250.25`) so that they belong to `Person1` in the first array.

Desired Output:

```
Array(
    [0] => 250.25 // for Person1 in the first Array after adding
    [1] => 157.15 // for Person2 in the first Array
)
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank You.

**P.S.**: All the values are coming from the database.

**EDIT 1**:
Here's what I have tried, but this outputs the second array as it is:

```
$sums = array();
$sums = array_fill_keys(array_keys($affiCode + $affiCommAmount), 0);
array_walk($sums, function (&$value, $key, $arrs) {
    $value = @($arrs[0][$key] + $arrs[1][$key]);
    }, array($affiCode, $affiCommAmount)
);
```

Comment: paste the code you have.Use a loop and add the first and second value; and put it in the first index

Comment: Can you tell us what you already tried? Or are you asking a question before you even tried something :) ?

Comment: Please check the question now..

Comment: The suppression operator (`@`) is used to hide errors, warnings, and notices. It can make problems hard to spot when debugging code. Consider removing it, at least while debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrays are the same size, so you can use a `for` loop to process them simultaneously:

```
for($i = 0; $i<count($personArray); $i++)
```

Within the loop, construct a new array keyed to the values from the first array. If the key does not yet exist, initialize it:

```
if (!isset($newArray[$personArray[$i]])) {
    $newArray[$personArray[$i]] = 0.0;
}
```

then add the new value to the selected array key:

```
$newArray[$personArray[$i]] += $valueArray[$i]
```

When the loop ends, `$newArray` will look like:

```
Array(
    ['Person1'] => 250.25
    ['Person2'] => 157.15
)
```

If you want to replace the 'Person1' and 'Person2' keys with numerical indexes, use `array_values()`:

```
$numericallyIndexedArray = array_values($newArray);
```

The final code looks like:

```
$newArray = [];
for($i = 0; $i<count($personArray); $i++) {
    if (!isset($newArray[$personArray[$i]])) {
        $newArray[$personArray[$i]] = 0;
    }

    $newArray[$personArray[$i]] += $valueArray[$i];
}

// Optionally return the new array with numerical indexes:
$numericallyIndexedArray = array_values($newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the person from first array by index and add the money:

```
for($i=0;$i<count(arrayPerson);$i++){
  $arrayPerson[$i]->addMoney($arrayMoney[$i])
  //Or  $arrayPerson[$i]->Money += $arrayMoney[$i]
} //$i defines your index in the array.
```

## sql

Better though to make a join in the SQL and sum the money and group by PersonID.

for example:

```
SELECT person.* COUNT(Money) FROM Person
LEFT JOIN Money 
ON person.ID = Money.PersonID
GROUP BY person.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple `foreach` loop:

```
$people = array('Person1', 'Person1', 'Person2');
$values = array(100.00, 150.25, 157.15);

$output = array();
foreach ($people as $key => $person) {
    
    if (! isset($output[$person])) {
        $output[$person] = 0;
    }
    
    if (! empty($values[$key])) {
        $output[$person] += $values[$key];
    }
}

// $output = array(2) { ["Person1"]=> float(250.25) ["Person2"]=> float(157.15) }
```

If you want to do away with the keys in `$output`, you can use `array_values($output)`

#### [Here's an example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/hYgGW1)